# jQuery change on click and if i click again change back

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have here an on/off button,

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#onOffButton").on("click", function(){
         $("#onOffButton").text("ON");
       });
    })
```

When i click back, i want to change the button to Off.

Comment: Back? you mean browser back button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#onOffButton").on("click", function(){
         var txt = $(this).text();
         $(this).text(txt=="ON"?"OFF":"ON");
       });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="onOffButton">OFF</button>
```